# What is the difference between these scripts? FreeCodeCamp Javascript recursion tutorial

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Here is the prompt:

> We have defined a function named rangeOfNumbers with two parameters. The function should return an array of integers which begins with a number represented by the startNum parameter and ends with a number represented by the endNum parameter. The starting number will always be less than or equal to the ending number. Your function must use recursion by calling itself and not use loops of any kind. It should also work for cases where both startNum and endNum are the same.

my attempt:

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (startNum > endNum) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const array = rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum);
    array.push(startNum);
    return array;
  }
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5));
```

(Wrong)

---

given solution:

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum < startNum) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1);
    numbers.push(endNum);
    return numbers;
  }
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5));
```

(Right)

Why do they not produce the same results?

Comment: Have you traced the code to see what it does?

Comment: Define “different results”—I mean it pushes different numbers so I don’t see how it could possibly be the “same result” even if the reversed logic was correct (I didn’t check). The result might be the same if the array was in the same order. Have you considered a debugger or some logging?

Comment: A note for the future... nobody wants to read a bunch of code all on one line. Consider your readers when writing something next time and proof read it before posting

Comment: Even if you wrote it differently, the first `if` condition is exactly the same. But the recursive call is clearly the other way around. So yeah, a different result makes complete sense.

Comment: Ah yes, clearly the other way around (I have been programming for 2 weeks).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just do not understand very well about the Running sequence of recursion and this is a very small bug in your code, so let's think differently,if we want to know rangeOfNumbers(1,5),we should known rangeOfNumbers(2,5) before,and if we want to know rangeOfNumbers(2,5),we should known rangeOfNumbers(3,5) before,until rangeOfNumbers(6,5),we know the result is [],
we got a pattern,

```js
rangeOfNumbers(6, 5); // []
rangeOfNumbers(5, 5) = rangeOfNumbers(6, 5).push(5) //  [5]
rangeOfNumbers(4, 5) = rangeOfNumbers(5, 5).push(4) //  [5,4]
rangeOfNumbers(3, 5) = rangeOfNumbers(5, 5).push(3) //  [5,4,3]
rangeOfNumbers(2, 5) = rangeOfNumbers(5, 5).push(2) //  [5,4,3,2]

// so,I think we could solve your problems just use unshift instead of push 
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (startNum > endNum) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const array = rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum);
    // array.push(startNum);
    array.unshift(startNum);
    return array;
  }
}
console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5));
```

Comment: I think I am starting to understand. Within recursion the "final" code (before the base condition) is called before anything else, then the 2nd to last, etc etc. So if you use a push call, the push does not happen top down, it happens bottom up. Is that on the right track?

Comment: yes,that's right

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm's execution can be envisioned as the conversion of a formal definition `range(start, end)` of an array into its practical implementation.

Through recursion: `range(start, end) -> range(start + 1, end)` you eliminate `start` from the beginning of the formal definition of the array.

When invoking: `array.push(start)`, you add the removed `start` to the end of the actual array. The method `push(item)` does indeed append the item to the end (the right extremity) of the array. This constitutes an error. If an index is removed from the beginning of the formal definition, it should be appended to the beginning of the actual array implementation.

The correct solution addresses this issue by appending the item removed from the end of the formal definition of the array `range(start, end) -> range(start, end - 1)` to the end of the actual array `array.push(end)`.